# Akka Source, is there a way to throttle based on a global rate limit coming from an api call?

Tags: scala, akka

There is the throttle function on Source https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/operators/Source-or-Flow/throttle.html but this only works in a local context (1 server). If I wanted to share a rate limit (for 3rd party api calls) with other servers (say I have 2 servers instead of 1 for redundancy), I'd like the rate limit to efficiently be spread across the 2 servers (if one server dies from out of memory, the other server should pick up the freed up rate limit until the dead server restarts).

Is this possible somehow through akka's Source assuming I have something like Redis returning whether an action is allowed or disallowed + what the time until an action will be allowed?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, you can dispense with Redis and use Akka Cluster to deal with failure detection: and set up an actor to subscribe to the cluster events (member joined, member left/downed) and update the local throttle.

Local dynamic throttling can be implemented via a custom graph stage (materializing as a handle through which to change the throttle), or you can also do that via an actor (in which case an `ask` stage is nice).  In the latter case, you can go further and have the throttling actors coordinate among themselves to reallocate unused request capacity between nodes.